# UltraSurf not working, used to work on same network (and is working fine on friend's computer on same network)

Tags: proxy, privacy

I'm using UltraSurf (10.17), it used to work fine but now its not working on my computer (Windows 7) and the window keeps showing "Connecting Server..." and after sometime, it fails to establish the connection. While, its working perfectly on the friend's computer on the same network. Any help will be appreciated. (Please note that using Proxifier would be my last option if I can't get UltraSurf working anyway).

Comment: Did you upgrade UltraSurf recently? Sometimes an upgrade causes an executable to change names and then Windows Firewall sees it as a different entry and blocks it.

Comment: @MaQleod: I checked firewall settings, also added UltraSurf as exception, manually but its not working.

Comment: Try to update it, to see if it works. (Current is 12.03)
Sometimes is normal to keep "Conecting" for a while, when the UltraSurf file is "new" in the directory.

Answer (score 1):

Check the "proxy settings" in the options window.

You will find a proxy setting button. Enter "proxy host" and "proxy port" like those that normally work for you.